# Как заменить цифры в двоичной CC на противоположные?

Tags: python

Существует последовательность чисел, каждое из которых переводится в двоичную СС. Как заменить в каждом из получившихся чисел 0 на 1, и 1 на 0?

```
for i in range(0, 256):
    b = bin(i)[2:].zfill(8)

#тут нужна замена

    print(b)
```

Comment: Беззнаковое bitwise NOT в помощь... `~b & 256`

Comment: Ещё можно проXOR'ить единичками. Вычесть из 255. Пройтись по строке в цикле и if'ом сделать замену. Или при помощи replace() сделать замену через промежуточное состояние. Или использовать регулярное выражение для обработки строки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Самое простое и короткое - использовать `str.maketrans` и `str.translate`:

```
t = str.maketrans('01', '10')
for i in range(0, 256):
    b = bin(i)[2:].zfill(8)
    b = str.translate(b, t)
    print(b)
```

Comment: Самое просто и короткое - это банально вывести числа в обратном порядке: от 255 до 0  `range(255, -1, -1)`. :)

Comment: @GrAnd Была у меня и такая мысль, но просили же замену сделать ))